# apply an advanced logics to generate a new pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, apply

In a Python 3 pandas dataframe,

```
a,b
100000,NaN
100000,NaN
100000,NaN
100000,500
10000,5000
```

I would like to generate a new column C based on the following logic:

```
def applyFunc(a,b):

    if a >= 25000 & b is not null:
        return b*0.3
    elif a >= 25000 & b is null:
        return a*0.3
    else:
        return 0
```

note that column a & b are floats, but can be null.

ideal output:

```
a,b,c
100000,NaN,30000
100000,NaN,30000
100000,NaN,30000
100000,50000,15000
10000,5000,0
```

I have tried the following:

```
df['c']=df.apply(lambda x:applyFunc(df['a'],df['b']), axis=1)
```

error:

```
TypeError: ('cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with testing misisng values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) and 
[`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
m1 = (df.a >= 25000) & (df.b.notna())
m2 = (df.a >= 25000) & (df.b.isna())

df['c'] = np.select([m1, m2], [df.b*0.3, df.a*0.3], default=0)
print (df)
        a       b        c
0  100000     NaN  30000.0
1  100000     NaN  30000.0
2  100000     NaN  30000.0
3  100000   500.0    150.0
4   10000  5000.0      0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! @jezrael!

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code:

> `a >= 25000 & b is not null`

You use bitwise conjunction `&` instead of boolean conjunction `and`, hence the type error.

This should work:

```py
a >= 25000 and b is not null
```

Comment: `null` isn't recognized by Python anyway, is it?

Comment: `null` has no special value; you can create an object named `null` and use it as you please. What the author must have meant is `None`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, using `None` sounded more appropriate